# Java XMLAssert failing despite the xPath seeming to assert

Tags: java, xml, xpath

having a serious problem with org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLAssert, I'm asserting on a Doc that has the following xml in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'WFWAFBA' with length = '7' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '3' for type 'ValidCode'. </faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using the following xmlAssert

```
XMLAssert.assertXpathExists("//soap:Fault[faultcode='soap:Client']", doc);
```

I've run it through outside xPath checkers and it finds the element. Anyone able to help?

Many thanks!

Edit: Namespace is set with

```
  HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
  m.put("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
  NamespaceContext ctx = new SimpleNamespaceContext(m);
  XpathEngine engine = XMLUnit.newXpathEngine();
  engine.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
```

Comment: Have you registered the namespace `soap`?

Comment: Hey, yeah I have.

NamespaceContext ctx = new SimpleNamespaceContext(m);
XpathEngine engine = XMLUnit.newXpathEngine();
engine.setNamespaceContext(ctx);